# Convert 24 bit 2's Compliment (MSB first) value to a voltage

Tags: c++, arduino, spi, 24-bit

I have an ADC (AD7767) that I am using to measure a differential signal. The data coming from the ADC is a 2's compliment MSB first 24 bit value. I want to convert this value to a voltage. The reference voltage being used is 5 Volts. I'm using the Arduino IDE. What I have so far is basically this:

```
const long minValue = 0x800000;
const long maxValue = 0x7FFFFF;
signed long result = 0;
....
long voltage = (result * 0x5) / maxValue;
Serial.println(voltage);
```

This prints a value of 0.

What the values are:

```
result = 1010101101010101
```

0x5: aka `Vref`

```
(result * 0x5) = 110101100010101001
(result * 0x5) / maxValue = 0
```

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916191/c-c-convert-24-bit-signed-integer-to-float may help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division result is always zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/division-result-is-always-zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yu're trying to store a fraction into a long. The result will always be zero. You need to cast one of the operands to double and store the result in a double.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in long type you're using.
It's integer one and as the result is less than 1 you have 0 as result.
Using floats you'll have:

(result * 0x5) = 110101100010101001 = 219,305

maxValue = 0x7FFFFF = 8,388,607

Result = 219,305 / 8,388,607 = 0.026 [Volts]